# IBM Alchemy Language Sentiment analysis in Java

Tags: java, ibm-watson, alchemyapi

I have a small dataset made of comments and I want to do sentiment analysis on them using Alchemy Language.

For every comment, I want to know if it is positive, neutral or negative.

I'm using Java but the documentation here: http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/?java#sentiment is not very useful!

There is no example with Java code yet (it says "coming soon"), only Python or Node.js which I'm not familiar with, at all.

I've put each comment in a list, now I want to feed each of them to Alchemy and save the result (positive/neutral/negative and the score associated) into a csv file.

The resulting csv should look like this:

```
comment, polarity, score
Excellent, happy to help!, positive, 0.0012
I really hate pizza!, negative, -0.045
```

I already have my API credentials, but I don't know what is the code for doing the sentiment analysis with them.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Try using the SDK. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk

Comment: Hi! Simon. I had a look at your link. Using the code provided there, I can get the sentiment (positive, negative or neutral) printed. What's the parameter for outputting the emotions detected and the respective confidence? Thanks.

Comment: Emotions can be done using Tone Analyser.